# Lidar com nomes de packages e de função dinâmicos

Tags: mvc, golang

Estou no meu primeiro projecto de Golang, que consiste num pequeno roteador para uma estrutura de MVC. Básicamente, o que espero que ele faça é pegar no URL do pedido, separá-lo em pedaços, e reencaminhar o fluxo da execução para o package e função especificados nesses pedaços, proporcionando algum tipo de fallback quando não existe correspôndencia para esses valores na aplicação.

Uma alternativa seria mapear em variáveis todos os packages e funções, procurando depois os pedidos no conteudo dessas variáveis, mas isto não é uma solução dinâmica.

A alterativa que tenho utilizado noutras linguages é lidar com esses nomes de uma forma dinâmica na referência ao package/função, em que a linguagem de alguma forma considera o valor da variavel em lugar de considerar o seu literal. Qualquer coisa parecido com:  **{packageName}.{functionName}()** . O problema é que ainda não descobri nenhuma forma sintática de fazer isto em Golang.

Agradeço as sugestões.

```
func ParseUrl(request *http.Request) {

    //out of this URL http://www.mydomain.com/controller/method/key=2&anotherKey=3

    var requestedFullURI = request.URL.RequestURI()      // returns '/controller/method?key=2key=2&anotherKey=3'
    controlFlowString, _ := url.Parse(requestedFullURI)       // returns '/controller/method'
    substrings := strings.Split(controlFlowString.Path, "/")       // returns ["","controller","method"]
    
    if len(substrings[1]) > 0 {

        // Here  we'll check if substrings[1] mathes an existing package(controller) name

        if len(substrings[2]) > 0 {
            // check if substrings[2] matches an existing function name(method) inside the requested package and run it, passing on the control flow
        }else{
            // there's no requested method, we'll just run some fallback
        }
    } else {
        err := errors.New("You have not determined a valid controller.")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}
```

Comment: Se você criar um `type X struct{}` e então `func (x *X) Funcao()`, você pode usar como `x.Funcao()`, assumindo que defina `var x X`.

Comment: Ao que deu pra entender, você está construindo uma API, e quer descobrir qual o controller e método estão sendo chamados pela URL, certo? Isso você irá fazer construindo routers e registrando seus métodos nele. O match da rota com os routers e métodos registrados não será feito explicitamente por você. Agora, se o intuito é explicitamente criar um url router próprio, é interessante começar com uma estrutura onde são armazenados padrões de urls e seus respectivos métodos, como um hashmap. Executando assim o método correto para cada match.

Comment: O que sucede é que isso obriga-me a registar todas as rotas possíveis, e a manter esse mapa atualizado sempre que há alterações. Vamos admitir um projecto médio, com 20 controladores, em que cada um tem 20 métodos. São 400 rotas. Não faz sentido mapear isto. O que se pretende é que o roteamento seja dinâmico, e que quanto o roteador não consegue encontrar o controlador/método que está a ser pedido devolva um erro 404.